# python/clojure equivalent to mathematica's NestWhileList

Tags: python, clojure, wolfram-mathematica

Impetus: I *was* looking for something in python which would get me

```
f([1,2,3]) == [[1,2,3], [2,3], [3]]
```

In clojure, this would just be `(nest rest #(not (empty? %)) lst)`, or it would if we had a nest function. Do we? I'm tired of staring at the clojure api list..

Better approaches in python or clojure would also be appreciated..

Answer (score 3):

```
data = [1,2,3]
result = [ data[i:] for i in range(len(data)) ]
```

Answer (score 3):

Return seqs:

```
user> (take-while seq (iterate rest [1 2 3]))
([1 2 3] (2 3) (3))
```

Return vectors:

```
user> (take-while seq (iterate #(subvec % 1) [1 2 3]))
([1 2 3] [2 3] [3])
```

I've seen this pattern packaged up into an `iterate-while` function, which is pretty much the same as your `nest` function:

```
(defn iterate-while [pred f x]
  (take-while pred (iterate f x)))
```

Note that `(seq x)` is equivalent to, and preferred over, `(not (empty? x))`

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this (the first thing that came to my mind, and I haven't been doing clojure recently, so it might not be the best solution):

```
(take-while identity (iterate next [1 2 3]))
```

Update:

This solution Justin suggested is preferable (shorter, `[]` input, etc.):

```
(take-whil­e seq (iter­ate rest ...))
```

Comment: This may or may not be an issue, but `(take-while identity (iterate next []))` returns `([])`. For this use case I would expect it to return just an empty list. Using seq/rest does that.

Comment: Justin, using `seq`/`rest` seems to be the better solution. Edited the answer accordingly. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

```
user> (reductions conj [] [1 2 3])
([] [1] [1 2] [1 2 3])
```

Gets you the empty version as well. If you want, you can instead do

```
user> (take-while identity (iterate next [1 2 3]))
([1 2 3] (2 3) (3))
```

or

```
user> (rest (reductions conj [] [1 2 3]))
([1] [1 2] [1 2 3])
```

Comment: And how would you make your first and last examples do what the OP asked for? So far, I found nothing better (at least to the eye) than the code from my answer an hour ago, which you included as your second example. Btw: I thought that somethig like that would at least be in contrib, but didn't manage to find it. Maybe I'm confusig it with Haskell's `tails` though.

Comment: (map reverse (reverse (reductions conj [3] [2, 1]))) yields 
((1 2 3) (2 3) (3)).   To get the vec structure of the OP, you would need (vec (map #(vec (reverse %)) (reverse (reductions conj [3] [2, 1])))) to yield
[[1 2 3] [2 3] [3]]

Comment: OP didn't specify whether order matters, so I see no reason to suppose that he finds any of my suggestions useless. I imagine he'd rather see several ways of doing something similar to what he wants; if he doesn't care about order them reductions is certainly a shorter, prettier solution.

Comment: I didn't want to say that your answer is useless, but wanted to know, if it is possible to get the right order with `reductions` in a sane way (i.e. without using `reverse`two times). If I thought your answer were useles, I would have downvoted.

Answer (score 1):

```
(partition-all 3 1 [1 2 3])
```

yields

```
((1 2 3) (2 3) (3))
```

if you want it in a vector format

```
(vec (map vec (partition-all 3 1 [1 2 3])))
```

p.s. the 3 and the 1 in partition-all prior to the [1 2 3] define that the vector should be partitioned in groups of 3, with a stepsize of 1, and are not part of the input vector. I use partition-all instead of partition, because partition-all doesn't mind about groups being shorter than the specified length of 3.

Comment: that's clever, but in the general case you have to replace 3 with (count lst)

Answer (score 0):

Python:

```
def f(l):
    while l:
        yield l[:]
        l.pop(0)
```

The copy (`[:]`) depends on whether you want a copy of the list or you are OK with modifying it in place. If you only need one of the sublists at a time, it may be faster to remove the copy and iterate over `f`.

Note also that a list is not the best data structure for this.